# Why does the prev node become set as Circular instead of _Node after adding a new node to a linked list?

Tags: javascript, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Does anyone know why the prev node is set to `Circular` instead of `_Node`?

I am trying to add a new node to the end of the linked list. I was expecting `prev` to be `_Node`. Instead, it is being set as `Circular`. Prior to this exercise before I saw `prev` being set as `Circular`, I didn't know circular linked lists existed.

**Console.log**

```
LinkedList {
  head: _Node {
    value: 'Apollo',
    next: _Node { value: 'Boomer', next: [_Node], prev: [Circular] },
    prev: null
  },
  size: 6
}
```

**LinkedList.js**

```
const _Node = require("./Node");

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.size = 0;
  }

  insertFirst(item) {
    if (this.head !== null) {
      const newHead = new _Node(item);
      let oldHead = this.head;

      oldHead.prev = newHead;
      newHead.next = oldHead;
      this.head = newHead;
    } else {
      this.head = new _Node(item, this.head);
    }

    this.size++;
  }

  insertLast(item) {
    if (!this.head) {
      this.insertFirst(item);
    } else {
      let tempNode = this.head;
      while (tempNode.next !== null) {
        tempNode = tempNode.next;
      }
      // *** I have no idea why prev becomes [Circular] ***
      tempNode.next = new _Node(item, null, tempNode);
    }
    this.size++
  }

  insertAt(item, index) {
    if (index > 0 && index > this.size) {
      return;
    }

    if (index === 0) {
      this.insertFirst(item);
      return;
    }

    const newNode = new _Node(item);
    let currentNode = this.head;
    let previousNode = this.head;

    currentNode = this.head;
    let count = 0;

    while (count < index) {
      previousNode = currentNode;
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
      count++;
    }
    previousNode.next = newNode;
    newNode.next = currentNode;
    this.size++;
  }
```

**Main.js**

```
const LinkedList = require("./LinkedLists");

function main() {
  let SLL = new LinkedList();

  SLL.insertFirst("Apollo");
  SLL.insertLast("Boomer");
  SLL.insertLast("Helo");
  SLL.insertLast("Husker");
  SLL.insertLast("Starbuck");
  SLL.insertLast("Tauhida");

  return SLL;
}

console.log(main());

module.exports = main
```

**Node.js**

```
class _Node {
  constructor(value, next, prev) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next || null;
    this.prev = prev || null;
  }
}

module.exports = _Node
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `Circular` is not an object type, it means that `console.log` found a reference to the object it's printing so it stopped going further in a loop. The `head.next.prev` is still of type `_Node` but it's the `_Node` object we're already displaying.

When `console.log(main())` attempts to show you what `head.next` is, it does the best it can. What it finds is that `head.next` is the "Boomer" item, and its `prev` value points back to `head`. So when it tries to show you `head.next.prev` it sees that it points back to the object (head) that it's trying to show you. That's a circular condition because if it tries to go further it will start showing "Apollo" again so it stops and outputs "[Circular]" to let you know it stopped for that reason.  I'll try to draw it out:

```
_Node: Apollo  <----------+  // this is the circular part
       next: Boomer  -+   |
       prev: null     |   |
_Node: Boomer  <------+   |
       next: Helo         |
       prev: Apollo  -----+
```

If it tried to follow `head.next.prev` it would be back to `head` again and be in an infinite loop, which it detects and stops.